# Wordpress custom form advanced

Tags: wordpress

just a quick one, are you aware of any wordpress form plugins that allow me to create a form and depending on which options they select, it will display a certain bit of information that submits to a selected email.

Im trying to achieve a web request form for clients and would like them to be able to fill out information as well as select a check box for a certain amount of questions. For example,"would you like to update your own content?"

if they check this box, i would like the form to render all the information in the form and then depending on which checkbox is selected it will give me a bit of content that is different. im trying to automate a proposal template so it writes all this content in an email so i can quickly do proposals for websites etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, gravity forms does this. And it's very easy too.

http://www.gravityforms.com/

It is called 'conditional logic'. You enable this on a field, which will display conditional drop downs which you can choose previous 'multiple choice' questions to base your conditions on.

Think you have to pay for this plugin but you could probably find version 4 as a download somewhere to demo before you buy.

You won't be disappointed.